# MediaWiki VisualEditor stuck loading in private wiki

Tags: node.js, mediawiki, wiki

I setup MediaWiki with VisualEditor.
I followed instruction on the [extension's wiki page](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:VisualEditor), cloned the git, installed Parsoid, added the necessary lines to get Parsoid to talk to the wiki even if it's private:

```
$local_ip = '127.0.0.1';
if ( $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] == $local_ip ) {
   $wgGroupPermissions['*']['read'] = true;
   $wgGroupPermissions['*']['edit'] = true;
}else{
   # Disable reading by anonymous users
   $wgGroupPermissions['*']['read'] = false;
   $wgWhitelistRead = array ("Special:Userlogin", "MediaWiki:Common.css",
   "MediaWiki:Common.js", "MediaWiki:Monobook.css","MediaWiki:Monobook.js", "-");
   # Disable anonymous editing
   $wgGroupPermissions['*']['edit'] = false;
}
```

and now I can talk to the API:

```
$> curl -L http://localhost:8142/localhost/v3/page/html/Main_Page

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html prefix="dc: http://purl.org/dc/terms/ mw: http://mediawiki.org/rdf/" about="http://localhost/wiki/index.php/Special:Redirect/revision/1"><head prefix="mwr: http://localhost/wiki/index.php/Special:Redirect/"><meta property="mw:articleNamespace" content="0"/><link rel="dc:replaces" resource="mwr:revision/0"/><meta property="dc:modified" content="2015-09-29T22:45:43.000Z"/><meta about="mwr:user/0" property="dc:title" content="MediaWiki default"/><link rel="dc:contributor" resource="mwr:user/0"/><meta property="mw:revisionSHA1" content="8e0aa2f2a7829587801db67d0424d9b447e09867"/><meta property="dc:description" content=""/><meta property="mw:parsoidVersion" content="0"/><link rel="dc:isVersionOf" href="http://localhost/wiki/index.php/Main_Page"/><title>Main_Page</title><base href="http://localhost/wiki/index.php/"/><link rel="stylesheet" href="//localhost/wiki/load.php?modules=mediawiki.legacy.commonPrint,shared|mediawiki.skinning.elements|mediawiki.skinning.content|mediawiki.skinning.interface|skins.vector.styles|site|mediawiki.skinning.content.parsoid|ext.cite.style&amp;only=styles&amp;skin=vector"/></head><body data-parsoid='{"dsr":[0,592,0,0]}' lang="en" class="mw-content-ltr sitedir-ltr ltr mw-body mw-body-content mediawiki" dir="ltr"><p data-parsoid='{"dsr":[0,59,0,0]}'><strong data-parsoid='{"stx":"html","dsr":[0,59,8,9]}'>MediaWiki has been successfully installed.</strong></p>

<p data-parsoid='{"dsr":[61,171,0,0]}'>Consult the <a rel="mw:ExtLink" href="//meta.wikimedia.org/wiki/Help:Contents" data-parsoid='{"targetOff":114,"contentOffsets":[114,126],"dsr":[73,127,41,1]}'>User's Guide</a> for information on using the wiki software.</p>

<h2 data-parsoid='{"dsr":[173,194,2,2]}'> Getting started </h2>
<ul data-parsoid='{"dsr":[195,592,0,0]}'><li data-parsoid='{"dsr":[195,300,1,0]}'> <a rel="mw:ExtLink" href="//www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Special:MyLanguage/Manual:Configuration_settings" data-parsoid='{"targetOff":272,"contentOffsets":[272,299],"dsr":[197,300,75,1]}'>Configuration settings list</a></li>
<li data-parsoid='{"dsr":[301,373,1,0]}'> <a rel="mw:ExtLink" href="//www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Special:MyLanguage/Manual:FAQ" data-parsoid='{"targetOff":359,"contentOffsets":[359,372],"dsr":[303,373,56,1]}'>MediaWiki FAQ</a></li>
<li data-parsoid='{"dsr":[374,472,1,0]}'> <a rel="mw:ExtLink" href="https://lists.wikimedia.org/mailman/listinfo/mediawiki-announce" data-parsoid='{"targetOff":441,"contentOffsets":[441,471],"dsr":[376,472,65,1]}'>MediaWiki release mailing list</a></li>
<li data-parsoid='{"dsr":[473,592,1,0]}'> <a rel="mw:ExtLink" href="//www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Special:MyLanguage/Localisation#Translation_resources" data-parsoid='{"targetOff":555,"contentOffsets":[555,591],"dsr":[475,592,80,1]}'>Localise MediaWiki for your language</a></li></ul></body></html>%
```

And I can see in the Parsoid log that it worked

```
[info][localhost/Main_Page?oldid=1] redirecting to revision 1
[info][localhost/Main_Page?oldid=1] started parsing
[info][localhost/Main_Page?oldid=1] completed parsing in 364 ms
```

Yet when I try to click the Edit button on the wiki page, it stays stuck with the blue bar loading (and no log or any output to help me debug...).

I am kinda stuck anyone knows what to do next to check what's wrong? 
What log can I check? Or do you have an idea?

Thanks !

Comment: Did you try the other solutions suggested on the extension's page? https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:VisualEditor#Linking_with_Parsoid_in_private_wikis

Comment: Yes I tried them all ... That was the first thing I tried

Comment: I don't know if you are just happened using lighttpd or not. I used lighttpd and had the same issue as yours, only have the blue bar and timeout. I switch to httpd, no any issue at all. But unfortunately, I couldn't to fault tracing it. But I'm pretty sure it was not php or fastcgi's issue. May be need some tuning on lighttpd side.